# C HTMLagilitypack exception help

Tags: c#

```
foreach (string mul in masterurlList)
        {
            HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(mul);
            List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();
            try
            {
                hrefTags = ExtractAllAHrefTags(htmldocObject);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            { }
```

I already have an catch(exception) in my code but what happens in on HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(mul) i get
WebException was unhandled.
The remote name could not be resolved: 'www.eonline.com'

I can't get rid of the try and catch that i have, and if i expand my try area i lose all my strings.  any help would be awesome!  And i know my DNS is good

Answer (score 0):

Expand the try area like this to keep your strings...

```
   foreach (string mul in masterurlList)
            {
                List<string> hrefTags = new List<string>();
                try
                {
                HtmlWeb hwObject = new HtmlWeb();
                HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument htmldocObject = hwObject.Load(mul);
                    hrefTags = ExtractAllAHrefTags(htmldocObject);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                { }
            }
```